# Using multiple PIVOTs JOINs and GROUP BYs for advanced report generation

Tags: join, pivot

I've developed a timesheet recording system, that allows users to record:

- **A Period of time** (9:00 to 12:00)
- **What they did during that time** (DutyActivity: 1 hour report writing, 2 hours training)

When they submit a timesheet, the system also records their GeographyId, RoleId, CategoryId (single ids) and AttributeIds (multiple ids) - which is a snapshot of the user at that point in time.

This recorded timesheet information can then be queried for reports. In it's simplest form the system will return a list of UserIds with a SUM of the `PeriodMinutes` for each recorded `DutyActivityId`. Which would look like the following:

[image: Simple results]

However what I also want to do is group by and return the recorded `AttributeIds` recorded with each timesheet (in the `TimesheetAttribute` table). However because there are multiple `AttributeIds` recorded for each timesheet, it's a little more complex.

My attempt at this creates the following report:

[image: Complex results]

**However the problem with this is** that the `SUM(PeriodMinutes)` for each `DutyCategoryId` returned is now too high. It appears my SQL to include `AttributeIds` for each timesheet is causing the `SUM` calculation to be made incorrectly.

I've created a ZIP containing SQL for the database schema plus data, along with the SQL for both queries I've screenshot'd here: [ZIP Timesheet example database](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26428893/Timesheet%20database%20example.zip)

**The information below is included in the ZIP, but I'm linking them here for ease of access:**

[image: Database diagram]

**Report on timesheets, without attributes grouping**

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
T.UserId,
T.RoleId,T.GeographyId,T.CategoryId,
TDA.DutyActivityId AS TypeId,
SUM(TDA.PeriodMinutes) AS Total
FROM 
Timesheet AS T

LEFT JOIN 
TimesheetDutyActivity AS TDA ON
TDA.TimesheetId = T.TimesheetId

GROUP BY
T.UserId,
T.RoleId,T.GeographyId,T.CategoryId,
TDA.DutyActivityId
) AS SourceTable

/* PIVOT against the known DutyActivityIds */
PIVOT
(
SUM(Total)
FOR TypeId IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
)
AS PivotType

ORDER BY UserId ASC
```

**Report on timesheets, with attempted attributes grouping**

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
T.UserId,
T.RoleId,T.GeographyId,T.CategoryId,
TA.AttributeId * -1 AS AttributeId, /* Multiply AttributeId by -1 in order to create negative Ids, so that two PIVOT operations can be used */
TDA.DutyActivityId AS TypeId,
SUM(TDA.PeriodMinutes) AS Total

FROM 
Timesheet AS T

LEFT JOIN 
TimesheetAttribute AS TA ON
TA.TimesheetId = T.TimesheetId

LEFT JOIN 
TimesheetDutyActivity AS TDA ON
TDA.TimesheetId = T.TimesheetId

GROUP BY
T.UserId,
AttributeId,
T.RoleId,T.GeographyId,T.CategoryId,
TDA.DutyActivityId
) AS SourceTable

/* PIVOT against the known DutyActivityIds */
PIVOT
(
SUM(Total)
FOR TypeId IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
)
AS PivotType

/* Also PIVOT against the known AttributeIds */
PIVOT
(
SUM(AttributeId)
FOR AttributeId IN ([-1],[-2],[-3],[-4],[-5])
)
AS PivotAttribute

ORDER BY UserId ASC
```

Comment: What would that report look like if you did it by hand?

Comment: @Catcall It would look like the first output screenshot I've listed, which shows the total minutes of each `DutyCategoryId` grouped by `UserId`, `RoleId`, `GeographyId` and `CategoryId` - but with additional columns listing whether or not that group of timesheets had a value for each `AttrituteId` recorded against it (A boolean flag for each possible `AttributeId`

Comment: @PeterBridger, this is a fairly involved question. You're more likely to get responses if you add DDL and test data scripts so people have something to work with.

Comment: @Mark-Storey-Smith Yes good call - I've completely re-written the question to focus purely on the issue and attached a ZIP containing all the SQL to re-create the issues shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get the required result by dropping the second PIVOT and `AttributeId` GROUP BY argument and instead using a LEFT JOIN on the attributes.

**This answer was provided by [visahk16](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/pop_profile.asp?mode=display&id=33104) on the [SQL Team](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=166497) forums:**

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
    T.UserId,
    T.RoleId,T.GeographyId,T.CategoryId,
    TA.[-1],TA.[-2],TA.[-3],TA.[-4],TA.[-5],
    TDA.DutyActivityId AS TypeId,
    SUM(TDA.PeriodMinutes) AS Total

    FROM 
    Timesheet AS T

    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT TimesheetId,
     SUM(CASE WHEN AttributeId ='1' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) AS [-1],
     SUM(CASE WHEN AttributeId ='2' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) AS [-2],
...
     SUM(CASE WHEN AttributeId ='5' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) AS [-5] 
     FROM TimesheetAttribute 
     GROUP BY TimesheetId 
     )AS TA ON
    TA.TimesheetId = T.TimesheetId

    LEFT JOIN 
    TimesheetDutyActivity AS TDA ON
    TDA.TimesheetId = T.TimesheetId

    GROUP BY
    T.UserId,
    AttributeId,
    T.RoleId,T.GeographyId,T.CategoryId,
    TDA.DutyActivityId
    ) AS SourceTable

    /* PIVOT against the known DutyActivityIds */
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(Total)
    FOR TypeId IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
    )
    AS PivotType

    ORDER BY UserId ASC
```